# Markdown notepad for iOS mac and web

Tags: note-taking, markdown

I'm looking for a markdown notepad similar to snippetlab or Quiver that supports iOS, macOS and possibly also web.
It happens several times that I need one note and I had neither my mac or my phone...

I'll add more details about the requests:
This software should support Markdown.
This software should have an iOS native app and a mac native app.
All the notes should also be visible from a website.

For example

- SnippetLab: Supports markdown, has a mac app but not iOS app and no web.
- Apple notes: iOS/Mac/Web ok but no markdown.
- Bear: iOS/Mac/Markdown ok, but not web

Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what features you need/expect?

Comment: I added more details right into the original post.